# Simple MYSQL Select from 2 Tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mysql tables, a current table and an archive table.  The archive table is an exact copy of the current table and contains old records.

Both tables contain an advert_id column.

I want to search both tables for a record where the advert_id equals a certain value.

If it doesnt exist in the first, search the second.

The only way I could get it to work was doing two select statements, one for the first table and then if the record wasnt found select from the second table.  How would I search both at once?

Comment: is there relation between 2 tables?

Comment: No there is no relation between the 2 tables, they are just the same but different data.

Comment: well, first thing came to my mind was: `SELECT ..., 'Table1' AS source FROM table1 WHERE condition X UNION ALL SELECT ..., 'Table2' AS source FROM table2 WHERE conditions X` (condition means, your advert_id plus additional ones). By the way... what you are doing is plain evil. Either you have a Foreign Key constraint to ONE Table... or not. Please consider stopping looking into "the old table just to be sure"

Comment: what happens if record is found in both tables?

Comment: The record will never be found in both.  The archive table is only populated each evening with records that have been deleted from the main table.  This is to keep the size of the main table small to improve performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below.

```
select * from Current where advert_id = 222
Union
select * from Archived where advert_id = 333
```

Comment: Thanks that worked when I used the same advert_id for each table.

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a shot here but this should work.

```
SELECT * FROM `current` WHERE id = :id
UNION
SELECT * FROM `archived` LEFT JOIN `current` ON archived.id = current.ID
WHERE current.ID IS NULL AND archived.id = :id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select * from Current a , Archive b where a.advert_id = 222 or b.advert_id = 222
```

This will search both the tables